# Rails add image to email template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, mailer

I want to add images or swag to email template,
Any idea for this bug

Sample :

```
<%= image_tag(asset_url('logo_grimaud.png')) %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
%div{:style => "background-image: url(#{ENV['IMAGE_URL']}/home.jpg);background-repeat: repeat;"}
```

This is how we did in one of our app. our images are already hosted on our severes. So `ENV['IMAGE_URL']` will be the app location where you have hosted your app.